# Calculating determinants using multiples

Tags: determinant

How would I simplify this matrix while calculating the determinant?

\begin{bmatrix}
    2/3 & -1/6 & -1/3  \\
    -1/3 & 5/6 & -1/3  \\
    -1/3 & -1/6 & 2/3
  \end{bmatrix}

The multiple is $1/18$ so

$$\frac{1}{18}
 \begin{bmatrix}
    12 & -3 & -6  \\
    -6 & 15 & -6  \\
    -6 & -3 & 12
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

Using row reduction operations $-R_2 + R_3 \to R_3$ and $2R_2 + R_1 \to R_1$

$$\frac{1}{18}
 \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -27 & -18  \\
    -6 & 15 & -6  \\
    0 & -18 & 18
  \end{bmatrix}
=  \frac{6}{18}\begin{bmatrix}
    27 & -18  \\
    -18 & 18 
  \end{bmatrix} = \frac{6}{18}(27 \cdot 18 - 18 \cdot 18) = 54$$

Answer is $1/6$. Where did I go wrong? I still wish to complete this with whole numbers

Comment: `1/18` No, that should rather be $\,1 / 18^3\,$ the way you worked out.

Comment: Ope. Got it. Thank you ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    2/3 & -1/6 & -1/3  \\
    -1/3 & 5/6 & -1/3  \\
    -1/3 & -1/6 & 2/3
  \end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{18^3}
 \begin{bmatrix}
    12 & -3 & -6  \\
    -6 & 15 & -6  \\
    -6 & -3 & 12
  \end{bmatrix}=\frac{972}{18^3}=\frac{1}{6}$$